# SSIS Format File

Tags: ssis, format

I have inherited a SSIS package which contains a bulk import task.
The bulk import tasks uses the following format file:

```
8.0
38
1       SQLCHAR       0       2       ""                        1     branch_code                      Latin1_General_CI_AS
2       SQLCHAR       0       10      ""                        2     sfkacct_number                   Latin1_General_CI_AS
3       SQLCHAR       0       3       ""                        3     sfkacct_depot                    Latin1_General_CI_AS
4       SQLCHAR       0       35      ""                        4     sfkacct_nominee_name             Latin1_General_CI_AS
5       SQLCHAR       0       2       ""                        5     sfkacct_domicile                 Latin1_General_CI_AS
6       SQLCHAR       0       3       ""                        6     secore_transaction_status        Latin1_General_CI_AS
7       SQLCHAR       0       11      ""                        7     secore_transaction_reference     Latin1_General_CI_AS
8       SQLCHAR       0       16      ""                        8     customer_reference               Latin1_General_CI_AS
9       SQLCHAR       0       35      ""                        9     market_reference                 Latin1_General_CI_AS
10      SQLCHAR       0       35      ""                        10    counterparty_reference           Latin1_General_CI_AS
11      SQLCHAR       0       2       ""                        11    transaction_type                 Latin1_General_CI_AS
12      SQLCHAR       0       18      ""                        12    security_quantity                Latin1_General_CI_AS
13      SQLCHAR       0       10      ""                        13    security_code                    Latin1_General_CI_AS
14      SQLCHAR       0       12      ""                        14    security_number                  Latin1_General_CI_AS
15      SQLCHAR       0       3       ""                        15    security_group                   Latin1_General_CI_AS
16      SQLCHAR       0       8       ""                        16    trade_date                       Latin1_General_CI_AS
17      SQLCHAR       0       8       ""                        17    contractual_settlement_date      Latin1_General_CI_AS
18      SQLCHAR       0       8       ""                        18    actua1_settlement_date           Latin1_General_CI_AS
19      SQLCHAR       0       8       ""                        19    revised_date                     Latin1_General_CI_AS
20      SQLCHAR       0       3       ""                        20    settlement_currency              Latin1_General_CI_AS
21      SQLCHAR       0       20      ""                        21    settlement_amount                Latin1_General_CI_AS
22      SQLCHAR       0       3       ""                        22    cash_currency                    Latin1_General_CI_AS
23      SQLCHAR       0       14      ""                        23    cashacct_number                  Latin1_General_CI_AS
24      SQLCHAR       0       10      ""                        24    broker_code                      Latin1_General_CI_AS
25      SQLCHAR       0       35      ""                        25    broker_description               Latin1_General_CI_AS
26      SQLCHAR       0       35      ""                        26    beneficiary_code                 Latin1_General_CI_AS
27      SQLCHAR       0       35      ""                        27    beneficiary_details1             Latin1_General_CI_AS
28      SQLCHAR       0       35      ""                        28    beneficiary_details2             Latin1_General_CI_AS
29      SQLCHAR       0       35      ""                        29    beneficiary_details3             Latin1_General_CI_AS
30      SQLCHAR       0       16      ""                        30    failcode_org                     Latin1_General_CI_AS
31      SQLCHAR       0       16      ""                        31    failcode_lst                     Latin1_General_CI_AS
32      SQLCHAR       0       35      ""                        32    failcode_description             Latin1_General_CI_AS
33      SQLCHAR       0       2       ""                        33    status_code                      Latin1_General_CI_AS
34      SQLCHAR       0       8       ""                        34    secore_transaction_inputdate     Latin1_General_CI_AS
35      SQLCHAR       0       8       ""                        35    secore_transaction_valuedate     Latin1_General_CI_AS
36      SQLCHAR       0       6       ""                          36    yearmonth                        Latin1_General_CI_AS
37      SQLCHAR       0       2       ""                        37    domicile                             Latin1_General_CI_AS
38      SQLCHAR       0       1       "\r\n"                    38    instruction_mode                 Latin1_General_CI_AS
```

Coudl anyone tell me what the 8.0 at the top of the file represents?

Comment: Could it be the number of columns in the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the version number of the bcp.
[MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa173859%28SQL.80%29.aspx)

It looks like
  SQL Server 2000 - 8.0
  SQL Server [2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191516%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) - 9.0
  SQL Server [2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191516%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx) - 10.0